# How to use leakcanary.AppWatcher in my java class?

Tags: android, leakcanary

I am trying to use LeakCanary to detect leaks in my Service class in my Android app,
and looking into below recipe:

```
https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#watching-objects-with-a-lifecycle
```

It is calling AppWatcher.objectWatcher.watch() to wath Service class, and I want to do the same.
From my code, I need to access AppWatcher object, but following fails with build.
("package leakcanary.AppWatcher does not exist", etc.)

```
import com.squareup.leakcanary.AppWatcher;
```

or

```
import leakcanary.AppWatcher;
```

I have already configured my bazle setting to include below in my dependency:

```
"com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:aar:2.4"
"com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-object-watcher-android:aar:2.4"
```

And, according to logcat log, LeakCanary instance is successfully invoked when I launch my activity.
(So, the library dependency itself is already OK, and I should be able to access AppWatcher singleton from my java code to watch my Service as well?)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the below compiles without error and watch() function seems to be called (in the logcat, LeakCanary says it is watching my Service.)

```
import leakcanary.AppWatcher;

...

  onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (AppWatcher.INSTANCE.isInstalled()) {
      AppWatcher.INSTANCE.getObjectWatcher().watch(
        this,
        "MyService received Service#onDestroy() callback"
      );
    }
```